# Multiple Non-Clustered index and performance?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, indexing

I have a table in SQL Server that has 700 000 records. But, when I am making a simple select query with 3 to 4 conditions in where clause, it is taking up to 45 seconds. I already have 2 non-clustered and 1 clustered index on that. So I was thinking to add 2 more non-clustered index in that table. By doing so, My table will have indexes for all columns which I am using in where clause of my query. I have also done it and found that result is coming quite faster as compared to previous one.

Can having 5 to 6 Non-clustered index can harm database performance or it would not affect much?

My Query structure is

```
SELECT ( SOME COLUMNS) FROM MyTable 
WHERE COL1 = @Id AND COL2 >= @SomeDate AND (NOT (COL3 = 1)) AND
(COL4 <= @SomeOtherDate)
```

Table has 35 columns.

Comment: As always it depends. Having 5-6 indexes is ok as long as they are necessary.

Comment: depends means ? How ? that is what I am asking. What are the cases ?

Comment: So, it is arguable and depending upon various factors. Answer is like @lad2025 said "it depends". I've tables with upto 5-10 indexes and it works super fast. Check covering index online for more details.

Comment: Share your structures and query you want to optimize. For now it is too broad.

Comment: I have updated my question.

Comment: When you are troubleshooting a query, you should also look at the query execution plan - that will tell you where the resources are being spent, and can give you an idea of where to focus.

Comment: More indexes rarely hurt `SELECT` performance, since if they are not used they are ignored.  They do impact `INSERT` and `UPDATE` performance since they need to be updated when the underlying data changes.  They also take up storage space, of course.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is your query:

```
SELECT ( SOME COLUMNS)
FROM MyTable 
WHERE COL1 = @Id AND COL2 >= @SomeDate AND (NOT (COL3 = 1)) AND
      (COL4 <= @SomeOtherDate)
```

Unfortunately, your query can only make direct use of two columns in this clause.  I would suggest the following *composite* index:  `(col1, col2, col3, col4)`.  This index covers the `where` clause, but can only be used directly for the first two conditions.

A clustered index would probably be a marginal improvement over a non-clustered b-tree index.

Note  if `col3` only takes on the values 0 and 1, then you should write the `where` case:

```
WHERE COL1 = @Id AND COL2 >= @SomeDate AND COL3 = 0 AND
      (COL4 <= @SomeOtherDate)
```

And use either `(col1, col3, col2, col4)` or `(col1, col3, col4, col2)`.

Comment: A clustered index is still a B-tree index, do you mean that a clustered index would be an improvement over nonclustered?

Comment: Only one clustered index (normaly it's primary key) can be define for a table. The rows are physically ordered following the clustered index. So don't define it on modifiable column(s).

Comment: @GarethD I believe Gordon stated it correctly.  The clustered index would only save you a few leaves, and thus only marginal improvements.

Comment: That's a good answer but I believe that separate indexes on COL1, COL3 and Col4 will be a better approach (however, clustered index will be captured three times) because in real world we use more queries for these columns (specially dates). Ex: Select x from table where col4 = @somedate. Unfortunately, SQL Server keeps statistics only for the first column in the compound index, so it should be chosen wisely. But for the query OP has mentioned I think this solution is appropriate.

Comment: @AnujTripathi . . . You may *think* that separate indexes would be useful, but composite indexes are usually better.